# Why is Angular date filter displaying wrong date?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a date input field, and formatting the selected date in my ui with Angular.  But the formatted date is always 1 day less than the selected date.  Why is that, and how can I fix it?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div>
    <label class="control-label" for="inputStart">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="inputStart" data-ng-model="startDate" /><br />
        Selected: <span>{{ startDate }}</span><br />
        fullDate: <span>{{ startDate | date:'fullDate' }}</span><br />
        mediumDate: <span>{{ startDate | date:'mediumDate' }}</span><br />
        MMMM d yyyy<span>{{ startDate | date:'MMMM d yyyy' }}</span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);
```

I have a fiddle that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wittersworld/uY3s9/

**EDIT:** I updated the fiddle with a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wittersworld/uY3s9/2/

Comment: In your fiddle dates look just fine.

Comment: @Stewie that's because Sarajevo is GMT+1.  If you try the OP's fiddle at 0:05 your time when GMT is 23:05 the previous day, it will look like the fiddle is showing one day later than you entered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a timezone issue.

If you enter a date of, say, June 8, 2013 into your date picker, that's midnight GMT.  If you live west of England, say, in the U.S., it's June 7, 2013.

Change the line

```
{{ startDate | date:'fullDate' }}
```

to

```
{{ startDate | date:'medium' }}
```

to see the time!

Comment: Thanks Ray!  That got me on the right track to a solution.  I found an article that helped me the rest of the way, and updated the fiddle with a working method.  http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329

Comment: Working link: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/