# AngularJS: displaying wrong date

Tags: angularjs

I have the following datetime:

```
2015-03-04T00:00:39+00:00
```

I am trying to display the date as follows using AngularJS

```
{{entry.entryDate | date:'MM/dd'}}
```

However, when I do this, it displays 03/03 instead of 03/04.

The date displays correctly for any time before 1900. But when a datetime is 1900 or later, it always displays 03/03 instead of 03/04.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

According to AngularJS documentation you can find  [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) , you can set timezone as shown below.

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

Comment: I want to simply display 03/04. However, it is displaying 03/03 instead.

Comment: could you share a jsfiddle with your question? My best guess was that there was something wrong with the timezones.

Comment: Yes, there was something wrong with my timezone, so I created a custom filter. Thanks.

Comment: please mark as answer if you are pleased with the answer. Best.

Comment: It's indeed probably a timezone issue. There is a GMT timezone in your string, and you're displaying it in your browser's timezone. Try {{ '2015-03-04T00:00:39'  | date:'MM/dd' }}.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom filter to format in utcTime. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003579/why-is-angular-date-filter-displaying-wrong-date) helped point me in the right direction.

[Why is Angular date filter displaying wrong date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003579/why-is-angular-date-filter-displaying-wrong-date)