# Angular date decreases a day in the output

Tags: angularjs, date

my web service is returning the date as

```
[{"id":2,"days":4,"date":"2015-06-21T00:00:00.000Z","name"
```

angular js code

```
{{day.date | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}
```

but the display is

```
06/20/15
```

on what end (client or server) should I fix it so it displays fine

**Edit:**

I read the answer, but my question is not only about the correct date but I need this specific format `MM/dd/yy`, the answers on the site is displaying the date as `Jun 21 2015` etc. which I don't need. Appreciate help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Angular date filter displaying wrong date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003579/why-is-angular-date-filter-displaying-wrong-date)

Comment: @Peter `{{ startDate | date:'fullDate' }}` will try but I need the US format MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: The format is not really the problem. The problem is the fact that it uses the local time of your machine. The time on your date object is `00:00` so if your timezone is for example -2 the time will go to `22:00` on the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

Use date format as below:

```
 {{ day.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
```

Working Plunker is here [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/T8zSS3i4dYgdZ5VOORHy?p=preview)

Comment: Maybe its me, but what is the difference to OP's code? I strongly suspect this is a timezone problem.

Comment: the plunkr is displaying wrong date in my machine, `Date: 06/20/2015`, how can I avoid this?

Comment: Yes It's timezone issue.  the Z at the end of the timestamp is shorthand for +00:00 aka Zulu time aka UTC / GMT. PLease check your timestamp and return value (time format) accordingly.